# How to check if a Double can be converted into a Int32?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a double value that I'd like to convert into a Int32. How can I check before converting if it can be converted?

Sometimes the value is undefined and the Converting into Int32 throws an OverflowException.

I already tried to test it that way:

```
double value = getSomeValue();
if (value == Double.NAN) {
value =0;
}
int v = Convert.ToInt32(value);
```

But this does not cover all cases.

Comment: Why is simply attempting the conversion and catching the exception not an option?

Comment: a value may never == NaN (value!=value is a valid NaN test, value==NaN - no)

Comment: I can hear that rocket exploding already.  Kaaaabooooom.  Youtube favorite though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this?

**Update**: I *believe* the update below addresses the edge cases. I've tested this against every case I could think of verifying the output against a method that attempts `Convert.ToInt32` directly and catches the exception.

```
static bool TryConvertToInt32(double value, out int result)
{
    const double Min = int.MinValue - 0.5;
    const double Max = int.MaxValue + 0.5;

    // Notes:
    // 1. double.IsNaN is needed for exclusion purposes because NaN compares
    //    false for <, >=, etc. for every value (including itself).
    // 2. value < Min is correct because -2147483648.5 rounds to int.MinValue.
    // 3. value >= Max is correct because 2147483648.5 rounds to int.MaxValue + 1.
    if (double.IsNaN(value) || value < Min || value >= Max)
    {
        result = 0;
        return false;
    }

    result = Convert.ToInt32(value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think the NaN check isn't needed(but of course not wrong either) because NaN doesn't fulfill the inequalities.

Comment: that's not a good approach.  you are just re-writing Int.TryParse yourself.  Int.TryParse returns 0 already and doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: @phillip `TryParse` requires conversion to `string`. And it has different behavior for doubles with non integral values. So this function is quite different from `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @phillip Int32.TryParse only takes a string. The above function is better because there's no need to convert to a string and back when you want to convert from a floating point number to an integer.

Comment: your argument is that a simple ToString on a built-in TryParse method is harmful and that mess of code is better?  when it could still throw exceptions...  Man - I don't know what to say then.

Comment: Note that this rejects a few valid values which are just outside of the interval. If that's a problem depends on the OPs requirements. It will reject `Int.MaxValue+0.1` but `Convert.ToInt32` would accept that value.

Comment: @phillip, read the second part of CodeInChaos's criticism or the comment I provided on your answer. `TryParse` only covers a *fraction* of possible scenarios. To make your idea work, you need to round, convert to string, then try to parse. Dan's approach eliminates that and simply tests the value against known boundaries.

Comment: @phillip: Whether the fact that `TryParse` requires constructing a new `string` object just to perform a numeric conversion is bad or not is a subjective topic, I will grant you. More importantly, using `int.TryParse` simply **will not work for the vast majority of `double` values that *can* be converted to integers**, namely, any `double` that is not a whole number. My understanding is that the OP wants a function that will determine whether calling `Convert.ToInt32` would work; the `int.TryParse` suggestion simply fails at doing that.

Comment: I think this is a teensy bit wrong on the boundaries. For example, if `value` is 2,147,483,647.01, `Convert.ToInt32(value)` would return `int.MaxValue`, but this method would have already kicked `value` out and returned 0.

Comment: @phillip: As for your claim about this code throwing exceptions, *that* I would like for you to explain if possible. I'm not saying you're wrong; I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, @MusiGenesis: Thanks for pointing out the edge case. Now I'm trying to think of the best way to handle that...

Comment: I think it's not +1 but just +0.5. I think Convert.ToInt32 rounds instead of truncating. But I don't know which mid-point rounding it uses.

Comment: @Code, neither value is appropriate, actually. So I removed my comment.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, @MusiGenesis, @Anthony Pegram: Fixed... I think?

Comment: @Dan, I believe so, you can't convert (int.MaxValue + 0.5d), but you should be able to convert a value less than that.

Comment: I would change the signature of this method to 

public static bool TryConvertToInt(this double value, out int result)

and throw it in a static class, so it becomes a extension method.

Comment: @Oakcool: That is always an option ;) I tend to err on the conservative side when it comes to extension methods; a lot of developers love them while a lot of *other* developers dislike that they "clutter" code completion features (e.g., Intellisense in VS).

Answer (score 3):

Check whether Double.IsNaN and make sure it's between int.MinValue and int.MaxValue,

Comment: If  `it's between int.MinValue and int.MaxValue`, it's not NaN by definition.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes.  I was trying to hint that ` == NaN` is wrong.

Comment: I, seriously, cannot consider anyone checking NaN w/ == and excepting any results, the person simply doesn't understand how NaN works.

Answer (score 3):

You could compare to the range of an Int32.

```
if(value <= (double)Int32.MAX_VALUE && value >= (double)Int32.MIN_VALUE)
    return (Int32)value;
return 0;
```

Of course, if you want to return Max/Min value when the double is too large, you could do this:

```
if(value <= (double)Int32.MAX_VALUE && value >= (double)Int32.MIN_VALUE)
    return (Int32)value;
if(value > (double)Int32.MAX_VALUE)
    return Int32.MAX_VALUE;
if(value < (double)Int32.MIN_VALUE)
    return Int32.MIN_VALUE;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
double d = Double.NaN;
int i;
if(Int32.TryParse(d.ToString(), out i))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
    Console.WriteLine(i);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Fail");
}
```

Comment: 1.4 will result in false but 1.4 can certainly be converted to an `int` (of 1).

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
(value>=Int32.MinValue)&&(value<=Int32.MaxValue)
```

This will probably falsely reject values which are outside the value range of `int` but get rounded into it. So you might want to extent the interval a bit.

For example `Int32.MaxValue+0.1` gets rejected.

How do you want to treat non integral doubles? This code accepts them and silently rounds away the fractional part. The suggestions based on `int.TryParse(value.ToString(),...)` will throw consider such doubles invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need the performance, what about using exception handling?

Comment: Bad for multiple reasons. For example it can get annoying with a debugger attached, and it's bad style too.

Comment: That is true... Exceptions should be reserved for unexpected rare situations. If the overflow is expected frequently, then it is indeed not the right method.